# Symfony framework.lock with .env set-up

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, locking, phpdotenv

#### Problem

I need to set up Symfony framework.yaml parameter `framework.lock` with 2+ memcached servers using `.env`. But when I try to do so, it does not recognize 2 servers, but only one, and with a glitch.

Symfony lock docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/lock.html

#### What I have tried (with code snippets):

##### Passing via .env

- I have `.env` file with the following content:

```yaml
MEMCACHE_SERVERS='memcached://m1.docker:11211,memcached://m2.docker:11211'
```

- Have `framework.yaml` file with following content:

```yaml
framework:
    lock: '%env(MEMCACHE_SERVERS)%'
```

- Have the following `controller method` to see a created lock object as a debug

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/example")
     */
    public function exampleAction(LockFactory $lockFactory): JsonResponse
    {
        dd($lockFactory->createLock('testing-lock', 2));
    }
```

- It returns the following. The `host` recognized as `m1.docker:11211,memcached"`, the second even not detected.

```
-store: Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\MemcachedStore {#22171 ▼
    -memcached: Memcached {#23004 ▼
      servers: array:1 [▼
        0 => array:3 [▼
          "host" => "m1.docker:11211,memcached"
          "port" => 11211
          "type" => "TCP"
        ]
      ]
      options: {▶}
    }
    -initialTtl: 300
    -useExtendedReturn: null
  }
```

##### Passing directly to `lock` parameter

- If I'm passing the values directly to `framework.lock`, without using .env. It works.

```yaml
lock: ['memcached://m1.docker:11211','memcached://m2.docker:11211']
```

- Result:

```
  -store: Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\CombinedStore {#22386 ▼
    -stores: array:2 [▼
      0 => Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\MemcachedStore {#23199 ▼
        -memcached: Memcached {#22471 ▼
          servers: array:1 [▼
            0 => array:3 [▼
              "host" => "m1.docker"
              "port" => 11211
              "type" => "TCP"
            ]
          ]
          options: {▶}
        }
        -initialTtl: 300
        -useExtendedReturn: null
      }
      1 => Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\MemcachedStore {#22514 ▼
        -memcached: Memcached {#22625 ▼
          servers: array:1 [▼
            0 => array:3 [▼
              "host" => "m2.docker"
              "port" => 11211
              "type" => "TCP"
            ]
          ]
          options: {▶}
        }
        -initialTtl: 300
        -useExtendedReturn: null
      }
    ]
```

#### Question

The question. How I can pass the 2+ memcached servers to framework. lock using .env?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`lock: '%env(MEMCACHE_SERVERS)%'` and `lock: ['memcached://m1.docker:11211','memcached://m2.docker:11211']` looks pretty different to me - I would assume that the array makes the difference here.

Please try to set the env variable such that it contains an array:

`MEMCACHE_SERVERS='["memcached://m1.docker:11211","memcached://m2.docker:11211"]'`

Afterwards, configure the lock such that it parses the given array:

```yaml
framework:
   lock: '%env(json:MEMCACHE_SERVERS)%'
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes, I have tried different ways, also the array look. Tried yours with json env-processor, but got following exception:

`Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidTypeException`
Invalid type for path "framework.lock.resources.default.0". Expected one of "bool", "int", "float", "string", but got "array".

Comment: Okay, according to https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/40906, this is an open bug report....

Answer (score 0):

### From answers

Nico Haase gave the answer. It's known issue http://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/40906.

###### Summary of github thread on problem:

"This issue is about a bug in Symfony where an environment variable cannot be parsed into an array. The bug is caused by the logic in the Configuration class. There are a few proposed solutions, but no consensus has been reached."

#### Custom solution 1. `Extension` approach

I have tried to invent the workaround with `AppExtension` and it works.

```php
    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $envName = 'MEMCACHE_SERVERS';

        $serversAsCsv = getenv($envName);
        
        if (empty($serversAsCsv)) {
            throw new LogicException(sprintf('Check that %s env is set and not empty', $envName));
        }

        $hostsList = str_getcsv($serversAsCsv, ',', '"', PHP_VERSION_ID >= 70400 ? '' : '\\');

        $container->setParameter('cache.memcached.servers', $hostsList);
    }
```

#### Custom solution 2 `framework.php`:

```php
use Symfony\Config\FrameworkConfig;

return static function (FrameworkConfig $framework): void {
    $framework->lock()
        ->resource('default', explode(',', getenv('MEMCACHE_SERVERS_2')))
    ;
};
```